# PyInstaller cannot find mscrp90.dll when building app on Windows; produced .exe cannot find imported module when run

Tags: python, windows, importerror, python-import, pyinstaller

I'm using PyInstaller to build my Python/wxPython project. It's made me a Mac app happily enough but I'm having some problems with Windows.

There are two issues. Firstly, errors when building the package. Secondly, strange error when the produced `.exe` is run.

**Errors when building**

```
29 INFO: Testing for ability to set icons, version resources...
29 INFO: ... resource update available
39 INFO: UPX is not available.
59 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
170 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
170 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
240 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
359 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
460 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
480 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
851 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with c:\Users\USERNAME\project
851 INFO: checking Analysis
851 INFO: building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc non existent
851 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
851 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executable
940 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
940 INFO: Found manifest c:\Python27\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
950 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
950 INFO: Found file c:\Python27\msvcr90.dll
950 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
950 WARNING: No such file c:\Python27\msvcp90.dll
950 WARNING: Assembly incomplete
950 ERROR: Assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
1030 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
1030 INFO: Found manifest c:\Python27\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
1030 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
1030 INFO: Found file c:\Python27\msvcr90.dll
1030 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
1030 WARNING: No such file c:\Python27\msvcp90.dll
1030 WARNING: Assembly incomplete
1030 ERROR: Assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
1141 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\_pyi_bootstrap.py
1151 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
1171 INFO: Processing hook hook-site
1180 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
1300 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
1300 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
1371 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
1492 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
1601 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
2052 INFO: Processing hook hook-pydoc
2193 INFO: Processing hook hook-email
2253 INFO: Processing hook hook-httplib
2292 INFO: Processing hook hook-email.message
2342 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py
2392 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_archive.py
2443 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_carchive.py
2483 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_os_path.py
2483 INFO: Analyzing project/main.py
2773 INFO: Processing hook hook-anydbm
2834 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml
2904 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.sax
2944 INFO: Processing hook hook-pyexpat
2953 INFO: Hidden import 'codecs' has been found otherwise
2953 INFO: Hidden import 'encodings' has been found otherwise
2963 INFO: Looking for run-time hooks
3334 INFO: Using Python library c:\Python27\python27.dll
3394 INFO: Warnings written to c:\Users\USERNAME\project\build\project\warnproject.txt
3394 INFO: checking PYZ
3394 INFO: rebuilding out00-PYZ.toc because out00-PYZ.pyz is missing
3394 INFO: building PYZ (ZlibArchive) out00-PYZ.toc
4436 INFO: checking Tree
4436 INFO: building because out00-Tree.toc missing or bad
4436 INFO: building Tree out00-Tree.toc
4436 INFO: checking PKG
4436 INFO: rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing
4436 INFO: building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
5598 INFO: checking EXE
5598 INFO: rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because project.exe missing
5598 INFO: building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
5598 INFO: Appending archive to EXE c:\Users\USERNAME\PROJECT\dist\project.exe
```

**Errors when running**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pykka
```

Why is it that when I build a bundle it discovers [Pykka](http://pykka.readthedocs.org) just fine, but when I build an `.exe` it fails so spectacularly?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my bad. I totally forgot to install the module `pykka` in the environment where PyInstaller could find it because I'm running in a VM.

`pip install pykka` fixed it for me.